# can't run "npm run deploy" throw er; //unhandled 'error' event while deploying the react app into Github

Tags: reactjs, git, npm

I am developing react app in my localhost and try to deploy the code into github page.

But while running the command `npm run deploy` its shows below error.

```
PS D:\Projects\portfolio-app> npm run deploy

> portfolio-app@0.1.0 predeploy D:\Projects\portfolio-app
> npm run build


> portfolio-app@0.1.0 build D:\Projects\portfolio-app
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  41.69 KB  build\static\js\2.b0b79569.chunk.js
  2.35 KB   build\static\js\main.2ad86f1d.chunk.js
  1.4 KB    build\static\js\3.dc241c04.chunk.js
  1.17 KB   build\static\js\runtime-main.b7252dff.js
  546 B     build\static\css\main.ab7136cd.chunk.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /me/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.

Find out more about deployment here:

  https://cra.link/deployment


> portfolio-app@0.1.0 deploy D:\Projects\portfolio-app
> gh-pages -b master -d build

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn git ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn git',
  path: 'git',
  spawnargs: [ 'config', 'user.name' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portfolio-app@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -b master -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio-app@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-04T14_20_16_803Z-debug.log
PS D:\Projects\portfolio-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ENOENT` means that a file does not exist. The `path` indicated is `git`. `gh-pages` is trying to use `git` but it seems that it can't find it. Make sure `git` is in your `PATH` or that the path is correctly [specified in your code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages#optionsgit).

If that doesn't solve the problem, you might get additional debugging information by [prepending `NODE_DEBUG=gh-pages` to your `npm run` command](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages#debugging).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the command **npm run deploy** on the gitbash.